# Mamp and aspx file shows source code only

Tags: asp.net, server, mamp

I'm trying to live preview my site using brackets and Mamp, however the site I am working on has .aspx files and the preview only shows me the files source code. What can I do to get it to show correctly?

Comment: MAMP only advertises support for Perl, Python and PHP. It doesn't come with ASP.NET support.

Comment: Macintosh and Apache don't run ASP.NET by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the ASP.NET documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#summary):

> Because ASP.NET 5 has completely decoupled ASP.NET applications from IIS or any other web server, it’s now possible to host ASP.NET applications on any number of different servers. ASP.NET supports three: IIS, WebListener, and Kestrel, which provide two great options for Windows environments and a third, open-source option that can be used on several different operating systems.

Ditch Apache (which doesn't appear to support ASP.NET) and install Kestrel (but note its [limitations](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#supported-features-by-server) and consider if you really want to use the combination of ASP.NET and not-Windows).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with languages other then html, CSS, and Javascript as I work mainly front-end. Am I able to use MAMP to set up a server and preview .html pages live? or does it need to be PHP?

Comment: MAMP is fine for serving static files (like HTML and images) and programs written in Perl, Python or PHP.